# Font problem with xelatex on Windows 8 64 bits

Tags: fonts, xetex, windows

Running xelatex with MikTex 2.9 on Windows 8.1 64 bits Arial Narrow font in bold turns into Arial bold. Arial Narrow bold is OK outside Latex. Did not have this problem on previous environment (Windows 7 32 bits). Any idea where this might come from?

```
\documentclass[french]{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\newfontfamily\headingfnt[]{Arial Narrow}
\newfontfamily\normalfnt[]{Arial}
\begin{document}

\Huge\headingfnt{Arial Narrow}

\Huge\normalfnt{Arial}

\Huge\bfseries\headingfnt{Arial Narrow}

\Huge\bfseries\normalfnt{Arial}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Not related to your question (I do not know a solution, too, for now): I wonder, that this actually works, but the commands defined by `\newfontfamily` are switches, so what you write in the body is in fact (note, linebreaks are removed in comments): “`\Huge\headingfnt Arial Narrow \bfseries Arial Narrow \normalfnt Arial
`”. I remember I’ve somewhere read, that sometimes the fonts must be selected by _filename_, maybe it was for XeTeX.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The example however shows that Arial Narrow without bold is properly loaded. Only bfseries turns it to Arial.

Comment: What I had forgotten: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works, if you define the new font family with the ***file*** name instead of the *font* name:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\newfontfamily\headingfnt[
BoldFont=arialnb.ttf,
ItalicFont=arialni.ttf
]{arialn.ttf}
\newfontfamily\normalfnt{Arial}

\begin{document}
\Huge\headingfnt Arial Narrow

\bfseries Arial Narrow

\normalfnt Arial
\end{document}
```

Note also, that with `\newfontfamily` you define a *switch* (as explicitely written in documentation), exactly like `\Huge` and `\bfseries` are switches.

Regarding your question, why only the bold version not is properly loaded, I do not know an answer. These sentences from `fontspec` documentation

> When you have a very large collection of fonts, you will sometimes not wish to have them all installed in your system’s font directories. In this case, it is more convenient to load them from a different location on your disk. This technique is also necessary in XETEX when loading OpenType fonts that are present within your TEX distribution, such as /usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/fonts/opentype/public . Fonts in such locations are visible to XETEX but cannot be loaded by font name, only file name …

are not valid for your (and my) installation situation.